# How to use Zend\Session in zf2?

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2

Does anybody try zf2? I can not understand new mechanism of using sessions in zf2. How can I write and read to/from the session in new zend framework?

Also I can not find any examples in the internet.

Comment: Did that answer really help? What did you end up finding?

Comment: I found an example in Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session.php. For example you can write to session like this `$session->offsetSet('email', $email);`, check that filed exists like this `$session->offsetExists('email')` and get field with this code execution: `$session->offsetGet('email')`. So, It's a that what I was looking.

Comment: Also session can be started by `$session = new Container('base');` where container is a `Zend\Session\Container`

Comment: I know this question is a bit old, but this question is popular due to search engines, so for those reading, here is an article I wrote about this subject. It should be good for getting started with sessions in ZF2. http://codingexplained.com/coding/php/zend-framework/using-sessions-in-zend-framework-2

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Some examples of zf2 sessions usage:

Session creation:

```
use Zend\Session\Container;
$session = new Container('base');
```

Check that key exists in session:

```
$session->offsetExists('email')
```

Getting value from the session by key:

```
$email = $session->offsetGet('email');
```

Setting value in session:

```
$session->offsetSet('email', $email);
```

Unsetting value in session:

```
$session->offsetUnset('email');
```

And other easy way to use session are:

```
$session = new Container('foo');
```

// these are all equivalent means to the same end

```
$session['bar'] = 'foobar';

$session->bar = 'foobar';

$session->offsetSet('bar', 'foobar');
```

Comment: Oh, please, don't use methods of **ArrayAccess** directly. This is moveton. `Zend\Session\Container` also implements custom **ArrayObject** that means you can set, get and check properties like you do it with object. See my answer above

Comment: In case of Notice or Warning you can use this like this: $session->offsetSet('admin', new \stdClass()); Then: $session->admin->username = 'John';

Answer (score 17):

Definitely yes, you should use **Zend\Session\Container**

Container extends of [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) and instantiates with `ARRAY_AS_PROPS` flag that means you can easily iterate through properties and read/write them, e.g.

```
use Zend\Session\Container as SessionContainer;

$this->session = new SessionContainer('post_supply');
$this->session->ex = true;
var_dump($this->session->ex);
```

First argument is session namespace and second — *Manager*. `Manager` is a facade for `Storage` and `SaveHandler` and it's configured with `ConfigInterface` in order to save your session data in DB or Memcache server.

Comment: Using underscores for protected fields or methods is not trendy anymore ;). Mainly because modern IDEs make the practice obsolete and the underscore makes stuff look ugly.

Comment: I am a beginner of zend. I want to know how to use SessionContainer in zf2. In my opinion, one web application should have only one sessionContainer,right? so how to get the sessionContainer in the controller and view?

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently working with zf2. I found usage of Sessions in:

`Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session.php`

Maybe you can find your answer there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use session in your login action, you can use: "`Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService`". It Authenticates the user and store session as well.

`getStorage()->write($contents)` will store the session.

Answer (score 0):

well here is the brief example. i have implemented regarding maintaining session on successful authentication of user.

```
<?php
$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
$DB = $registry['DB'];
$authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($DB);
$authAdapter->setTableName('user');
$authAdapter->setIdentityColumn("user_name");
$authAdapter->setCredentialColumn("user_password");
//get values
$username = $request->getParam('username');
$password = $request->getParam('password');
//set values
$authAdapter->setIdentity($username);
$authAdapter->setCredential($password);

$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
//to store in session
$auth->setStorage(new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session('front'));

$authResult = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);
if ($authResult->isValid()) {
    $authAdap = $authAdapter->getResultRowObject(null, "Password");
    $auth->getStorage()->write($authAdap);
    $this->_redirect('/login/controlpannel');
} else {
    $this->_redirect('/login/login');
}
?>
```

getting values or check data stored in session related to user

```
<?php
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$auth->setStorage(new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session('front'));
 if($auth->hasIdentity()){
     $data = $auth->getStorage()->read();
     print_r($data);
 }else{
     $this->_redirect('/login/login');
 }
?>
```

hope this could help someone

Comment: This answer was posted on July 11, 2014, not in July of 2011.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Zend\Session\Container; 

public function createAction(){
  $session = new Container('name');
  $session->offsetSet('session_variable', $value);
}
//the above codes are used for create session.

public function take_valuesAction(){ 
  $session = new Container('name');
  echo $value = $session->offsetGet('session_variable');
}
//the above codes are used for take values from session.

public function destroyAction(){ 
  $session = new Container('name');
  $session->getManager()->destroy();
}
//the above codes are used for destroy the session.
```

Answer (score -1):

To start a session you need to use

```
zend\session\container
```