# How translate PHP code to Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2, zend-auth, zend-session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use Zend\Session in zf2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990195/how-to-use-zend-session-in-zf2)

I begin with `ZF2` but I can't continue because I don't understand the official `ZF2` documentation.

I run version 2.0.4.

How can I simply translate this PHP code into ZF2?:

**include.php**

```
session_start();
```

**index.php**

```
$_SESSION['login'] = 'toto';
```

**otherpage.php**

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['login']) ) echo $_SESSION['login'];//view toto
```

I tried with `Zend\Authentification\Storage\Session` and `Zend\Session` but nothing worked.

Comment: Quite the same, and answers the question too.

Comment: Question is fundamentally wrong, because ZF2 framework itself is a PHP code, and you cannot convert PHP code into PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

Zend is a framework and there is no way to "simply translate" PHP to Zend. Just look at functionality you are trying to achieve, and see if there is classes provided by Zend, that could replicate it.

You will basically have to completely rewrite the whole thing, because Zend strictly enforces MVC pattern.

Comment: My example is maybe bad. I use the model MVC but i don't succeed recover the session in my controller.
And the topic refers to duplicate doesn't detail the process

Comment: so you basically just looking how to mimick that behaviour? In that case cant help, don't have any experience with Zend.