# How to retrieve values from Zend frame work 2 sessions?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i just got a dump on Session in ZF2

```
Zend\Session\Storage\SessionStorage Object
(
[isImmutable:protected] => 
[storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
    (
        [__ZF] => Array
            (
                [_REQUEST_ACCESS_TIME] => 1359526796.5079
                [FlashMessenger] => Array
                    (
                        [EXPIRE_HOPS] => Array
                            (
                                [hops] => 1
                                [ts] => 1359526775.9345
                            )

                    )

            )

        [FlashMessenger] => ArrayObject Object
            (
                [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                    (
                        [default] => Zend\Stdlib\SplQueue Object
                            (
                                [flags:SplDoublyLinkedList:private] => 4
                                [dllist:SplDoublyLinkedList:private] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Authentication successful.
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [zf_tutorial] => ArrayObject Object
            (
                [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                    (
                        [storage] => hello
                    )

            )

        [zftutorial] => ArrayObject Object
            (
                [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                    (
                        [role] => user
                    )

            )



    )
)
```

i just dont know how to get retrieve

> [role] => user

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Zend\Session in zf2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990195/how-to-use-zend-session-in-zf2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990195/how-to-use-zend-session-in-zf2)

Some examples of zf2 sessions usage:

Session creation:

```
use Zend\Session\Container;

$session = new Container('zftutorial');
```

Check that key exists in session:

```
$session->offsetExists('role')
```

Getting value from the session by key:

```
$role= $session->offsetGet('role');
```

Setting value in session:

```
$session->offsetSet('role', $role);
```

Comment: do i need to create New Container for session? everytime i want to retrieve value?

Comment: according to my knowledge, if you already have a container you can use it. You don't have to create a new one if one exists.

Comment: due to my lack of knowledge i wanna ask that how to see/find if i already have a container intialzied? I mean some dump that can help me with it tho i can create new 1.

Comment: @noobie-php The Container is like a Namespace. Ultimately it doesn't matter if you do something like `new Storage()` or new `new Container('namespace')` going by the amount of code needed. It's not even that much more than to write `$_SESSION['namespace']` and has the same effect. It's a cleaner way of coding, that's all

Comment: @Sam agree, and got your point, My only concern was regarding memmory consumption thing ... so i think u cleared that thing.

Comment: Don't bother about memory ;) Don't "pre-optimize" your code - ever! Optimize where there are bottlenecks :>

Comment: 1 more quick thing is there a way by which i can see that what namespace current Container is holding besides taking dump?

Comment: Yes `$container->getName()` See https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Session/Container.php#L117